# Postgresql: UPDATE before INSERT function

Tags: postgresql, triggers

I have problem when create function for trigger. I want to UPDATE inserted value BEFORE INSERT data to DB.
My code look like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_func()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS 
$$
DECLARE cnt INTEGER;
BEGIN
    cnt := COUNT(*) FROM sample_tbl WHERE id = NEW.id AND created_date = NEW.created_date;
    NEW.current_order := cnt + 1; // I want to set value of sample_tbl.current_order automatically
END 
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;


CREATE TRIGGER test_trigger
BEFORE INSERT
ON test_tbl
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE test_func();
```

I inserted data then IDE said:
`control reached end of trigger procedure without RETURN
Where: PL/pgSQL function test_func()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error says that you must return something from the Trigger ( either `NEW` or `NULL` )

There's no Trigger needed for this. A simple `View` using this select query will give you the required result

```
--create or replace view sample_view as
select t.id, t.created_date,
       row_number() OVER ( partition by  id,created_date order by id ) as current_order
FROM sample_tbl t;
```

This will exactly match the records if updated using a Trigger

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_func()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS 
$$
DECLARE cnt INTEGER;
BEGIN
    select COUNT(*) INTO cnt FROM sample_tbl WHERE id = NEW.id 
      AND created_date = NEW.created_date;
    NEW.current_order := cnt + 1; 
RETURN NEW; --required
END 
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

[**Demo**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=2a853c5958eb3defe3dd44db9088682a)

Comment: Very easy to understand

Answer (score 2):

Your trigger function is just missing `RETURN NEW;` statement:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_func()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS 
$$
DECLARE cnt INTEGER;
BEGIN
    cnt := COUNT(*) FROM sample_tbl WHERE id = NEW.id AND created_date = NEW.created_date;
    NEW.current_order := cnt + 1;
    RETURN NEW;
END 
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```